# How come $A = Cd/\varepsilon_0$ produces the unit of m$^2$?

Tags: capacitance, units

The formula for getting the area in of a capacitance of a parallel-plate capacitor in a vacuum is this

$$A=\frac{Cd}{\varepsilon_0}.$$

In the sample problem of my book it was used like this

$$
A = \frac{245\times10^{-12}\:\mathrm F\times 0.328\times 10^{-3}\:\mathrm m}{8.854\times10^{-12}\:\mathrm{ C^{2}/ N\cdot m}^{2}}
$$

I am trying to understand how come that the unit result is $9.08\times 10^{-3}\:\mathrm m^2$.

How does it become $\mathrm m^2$?

Comment: Look up what a farad is.

Comment: @Cary Note that you can just use LaTeX notation directly.

Comment: I haven't voted to put this on hold because I'm having a hard time stating the reason for it to be on hold. Homework-like doesn't apply because the question does ask a specific conceptual question (i.e. it doesn't ask for the solution to the sample problem), and it does show work... the only problem is that the amount of additional work which would be needed to answer it is just so trivial.

Comment: i am voting to close the question.

Comment: @Lamichhane88 Read more about closing questions [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (available at 3.000 reputation). From 15 reputation you can [flag posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), including flagging as off-topic (which puts posts on the close-vote review queue).

Comment: @DavidZ I have exactly the same problem with this and several others.  There needs to be a "You need to go think about this again on your own." type of response.  That's the polite way of saying which I really think.  I think some people use the unclear question reason for things like this. That's not exactly right, but it's close to "are you actually asking what I think you're asking?"

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't know that the Eo units can also be written as F/m. It seems basic, but it wasn't discussed to me by my professor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit of $\epsilon_0$ can also be written as $[\epsilon_0] = \frac{\text{F}}{\text{m}}$ (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity))

With this it is easy to see that

$$\frac{\text{F} \cdot \text{m}}{\frac{\text{F}}{\text{m}}} = \frac{\text{m}}{\frac{1}{\text{m}}}  = \text{m}^2.$$